# PDO binds n times same value with foreach

Tags: php, binding, pdo, foreach, prepared-statement

I have function in PHP, which should bind in MySQL IN statement so many variables, that is in array.
My problem is that variable and key is changing but function bind only last value n times.

I don't have idea where is the problem...

**Here is my class method:**

```
public function getOtListByOtNumbers($conditions){
        $data_array = $conditions[SEARCH_OT];
    # To find last key (remove coma)
        $quantity = count($data_array);
        $marks = '';
    # Bind name string && rewriting value as integer
        foreach ($data_array as $key => $value){
            $i = $key+1;
            if ($i == $quantity){
                $marks .= ':key'.$i;
            }
            else {
                $marks .= ':key'.$i.', ';
            }
        }
    # Query
        $sql="
        SELECT
            c_int_id,
            c_ot,
            c_tickets_amount,
            c_basket_value,
            c_person,
            c_company,
            c_city,
            c_package_number,
            c_delivery_method,
            c_ot_date,
            c_email,
            c_phone,
            c_comment,
            c_send
        FROM ws_orders
        WHERE c_ot IN (".$marks.")
        ORDER BY c_int_id DESC
        LIMIT :first, :last ";
        $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($sql);

    # Bind n values
    // Here is a problem
        var_dump($data_array); // var dump 1
         foreach ($data_array as $key => $param){
            $key_number = $key +1;
            $key_name = 'key'.$key_number;
            $stmt->bindParam($key_name, $param, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            var_dump($key_name); // var dump 2
            var_dump($param); // var dump 3
        }

    # Bind limit values
        $stmt->bindParam('first', $conditions[OT_SEARCH_FIRST_ROW], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam('last', $conditions[OT_SEARCH_ROW_LIMIT], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    # If executed return result
        if ($stmt->execute() != FALSE) {
            $stmt_result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $stmt->closeCursor();
            var_dump($stmt_result); // var dump 4

    # If not executed print debug and return FALSE
        } else {
            var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
            $this->debugQuery($stmt);
            $stmt_result = FALSE;
        }

        return $stmt_result;
    }
```

**Here are var dupms:**

*var dump 1*

```
array (size=2)
 0 => string '2761531'
 1 => string '2760650'
```

*var dump 2 & 3*

```
string 'key1' (length=4)

string '2761531'

string 'key2' (length=4)

string '2760650'
```

**SQL query from this execution**

```
        SELECT
            c_int_id,
            c_ot,
            c_tickets_amount,
            c_basket_value,
            c_person,
            c_company,
            c_city,
            c_package_number,
            c_delivery_method,
            c_ot_date,
            c_email,
            c_phone,
            c_comment,
            c_send
        FROM ws_orders
        WHERE c_ot IN ('2760650', '2760650')
        ORDER BY c_int_id DESC
        LIMIT 0, 30
```

So what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

---

---

---

So i did it ;)
The problem was with foreach

Instead of:

```
     foreach ($data_array as $key => $param){
        $key_number = $key +1;
        $key_name = 'key'.$key_number;
        $stmt->bindParam($key_name, $param, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        var_dump($key_name); // var dump 2
        var_dump($param); // var dump 3
    }
```

I give:

```
        for ($key_number = 0; $key_number < $quantity + 1; $key_number++) {
            $key_name = 'key'.$key_number;
            $stmt->bindParam($key_name, $data_array[$key_number], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }
```

And it works, but i still don't know what the problem was with earlier foreach...

Comment: Good you got it to work! you should answer the question and accept it yourself. It is a recommendable way to "close" the question.

Comment: I have less than 10 rep, so i cannot do it before 8 hours :)
Maybe somebody, will describe why foreach doesn't work

Comment: Have helped a little :-) Dont know about the `foreach` - as I thought when I saw the question, there must be something about `$conditions`, maybe it does not quite contain what there is expected. Dont have the time right now, though - sry

Comment: `$conditions` is multidimensional array, but i use from it only one sub array, content of this array is listed _in var dump 1_. Data in each loop is changing (_var dump 2 & 3_ listing), but bindParam do not see it

Answer (score 5):

There is the difference between [**`PDO::bindParam()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and [**`PDO::bindValue()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). `PDO::bindParam` **binds reference**, not value. When foreach process ends, `$param` will reference to the last array value. In the time of `execute` call all binded references will be evaluated to same value.

Official `PDO::bindParam` documentation says:

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference
>   and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is
>   called.

If you want bind values in `foreach` use `PDO::bindValue`.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the variable as reference it would work fine for value, but won't work for key.

**Example:**

```
foreach ($data_array as $key => &$param) {
    $key_number = $key + 1; //this won't work
    $key_name   = 'key' . $key_number;
    $stmt->bindParam($key_name, $param, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    var_dump($key_name);    // var dump 2
    var_dump($param);       // var dump 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that BindParam Passes the second value by reference.  PHP reuses (or appears to in this case) the address of the $param, and not the actual value.
Your foreach could have used:

```
$stmt->bindParam($key, $data_array[$key]);
```

This has the effect of binding the address location of the array at that key location, so when your sql executes, it gets the right value.

You probably wanted:

```
$stmt->bindValue($key, $param);
```

which should evaluate in the foreach loop instead of at the execute statement, and is a passed value instead of an address location.